# Android: Code not working when getting list of all images

Tags: android

I have this code, to get all the photos saved on the phone.

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
final Cursor cursor =      context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null);

 return cursor.getCount();
```

I am always getting the size of cursor as 0, when I try using this on emulator or on my phone. Any pointer will be helpful.

I really don't know how to test this on emulator.

I have the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-images-sd-card
I'm betting you've added the wrong query `MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` - in the tutorial he uses `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.
Also that permission doesn't do anything but scare you're users, if you don't intend to save anything on to the SD card.

Comment: Hi Darwind, Thanks for your comments. Just for a chance I changed the     INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to     EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and it worked! I am surprised because I do not have a SD card on my phone (Nexus 4). I guess even though android assumes it to be an internal SD card.
I am now getting count of Photos on my view. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. ;-) Yes the internal storage on the Nexus should be reported as external storage. I believe this is by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code that worked.

```
public ArrayList<String> getCameraImages(Context context) {

    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};


    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());

    Log.i("cursor.getCount()) :", cursor.getCount() + "");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        do {
            final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            Log.i ("data :",data );
            result.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return result;

}
```